# Сделал всю игру в одном классе MyGdxGame, как сделать главное меню?

Tags: android, libgdx, mobile-development

Привет, у меня большая проблема. 
Дело в  том, что я написал всю игру в одном классе MyGdxGame наследуемый от ApplicationAdapter. Как мне сделать главное меню? Чтобы при открытии игры открывалось главное меню, в котором 1 кнопка, при нажатии которой открывалась сама игра(MyGdxGame)?
Просто скажите, как мне это сделать(что создать, что поменять)

Comment: Не знаю как libgdx работает и что из себя представляет проект и приложение, но отдельные экраны делаются через `Activity`. Т.е., по идее, вам надо 2 активити. Первая с кнопкой, вторая - с вашей игрой.

Comment: да, это в обычном android studio так работает легко, но не в libgdx

Comment: Ээээ.... LibGDX тоже запускается в активности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из способов. Всё рисуется, обрабатываются нажатия и прочее в одном классе. Но ты указываешь, что именно тебе нужно рисовать, обрабатывать, из какого класса. Но придется передавать объект класса по всем экранам, чтобы был доступ к переключению (final game)

создаешь класс экран, который ты будешь потом менять(переход из меню в другой меню, или в игру). Все классы, которые у тебя в дальнейшем станут экранами, наследуются от него.

```
public class UserScene implements Screen {

public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}
```

}

В главном классе

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game implements InputProcessor{
UserScene userScene;
MyGdxGame(){
    this.setUserScene(new MainMenuScreen(this)); // переключение экрана на класс MainMenuScreen
}

public void setUserScene(UserScene us){ // функция, которую будешь вызывать для переключения экрана на другой класс
    userScene=us;
    this.setScreen(us);
}
```

Пример меню

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends UserScene{
final ReactionTeacher game;

public MainMenuScreen(final MyGdxGame gam) {
    game = gam;}

// все Override из UserScene


textButtonBack.addListener(new ClickListener() { // кнопка для перехода из главное меню в экран игры
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            dispose();
            game.setUserScene(new MainGame(game)); // переключение экрана на класс MainGame
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создайте класс наследованый от Screen, например MyScreen, перенесите туда свою игру из MyGdxGame.
Далее, создайте MenuScreen, в нём отрисовка меню, и запуск игры, через mGame->setScreen( new MyScreen() );
Так же советую создать кеши скринов, чтобы не создавать лишних инстансов  скринов
Тогда вызов будет
mGame->setScreen( MyScreenCache.getInstance().getScreen( eScreen.Game ) );
или
mGame->setScreen( MyScreenCache.getInstance().getScreen( eScreen.Menu ) );
Заполнить MyScreenCache скринами в MyGdxGame

Вот мой пример кеша скринов

```
public class ScreensCache
{
    public enum eScreenType
    {
        EquationSolver,
        Graph,
        Settings
    }

    private static ScreensCache mInstance = new ScreensCache();
    public static ScreensCache getInstace()
    {
        return mInstance;
    }

    private Map<eScreenType, Screen> mCache = new HashMap<eScreenType, Screen>();

    public Screen get( eScreenType type )
    {
        Screen screen = mCache.get( type );
        if( null != screen)
        {
            return screen;
        }
        switch( type )
        {
            case EquationSolver:
                    screen = new EquationSolverScreen();
                break;
            case Graph:
                    screen = new GraphScreen();
                break;
            case Settings:
                    screen = new SettingsScreen();
                break;
        }
        mCache.put( type, screen );
        return screen;
    }
}
```

и стека скринов

```
public class ScreensStack
{
    private static ScreensStack mInstance = new ScreensStack();

    public static ScreensStack getInstance()
    {
        return mInstance;
    }

    private Stack<Screen> mScreensStack = new Stack<Screen>();
    private Game mGame;

    public void setGame( Game game )
    {
        mGame = game;
    }

    public void push( Screen screen )
    {
        mScreensStack.push( screen );

        mGame.setScreen( screen );
    }

    public void pop()
    {
        mScreensStack.pop();
        if( true == mScreensStack.empty() )
        {
            Gdx.app.exit();
            return;
        }
        mGame.setScreen( mScreensStack.lastElement() );
    }
}
```

Теперь когда пользовать будет перемещаться Меню <-> Игра, будет добавляться/удаляться скрины из стека

```
public class GraphGame extends Game
{
    @Override
    public void create()
    {
        final Screen screen = ScreensCache.getInstace().get( ScreensCache.eScreenType.EquationSolver );

        Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey( true );
        ScreensStack.getInstance().setGame( this );
        ScreensStack.getInstance().push( screen );
    }
}
```

когда не нужен больше скрин, то

```
ScreensStack.getInstance().pop();
```

Comment: что значит кеши скринов и инстансы? кеши это методы и переменные? а инстансы что? Кеши скринов - класс типа Resourse.java в котором храняется все переменные и функции, я так понял?

Comment: Получилось сделать?